# Parse | Cloud code current user

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, cloud

I try to get the current user with cloud code.

```
var verificationCode = (Math.floor(Math.random()*900000)) + 100000 ;
var user = Parse.User.current();
user.set("phoneVerificationCode", verificationCode);
user.save();
```

when I called the method in Xcode.

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendVerificationCode", withParameters:["phoneNumber": phoneNumberText])
```

it send but I get this error:

> Error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of null

what should I do?

Comment: ckeck your `user.set` once again may be there is a problem.

Comment: The class is "User" right? and Yes, the key "phoneVerificationCode" is ok.

Comment: You can't get current user from cloude code. Current user saved locally in client side. For more info see this link https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-current

Comment: I want to create new user when a verification code is send. after that create new username and password.

Comment: Did you find a solution fro this? Im having the same problems @user1809478

Answer (score 1):

The current user *is* available, if they are logged in. The user is passed in via the request object to your cloud function.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("myFunction", function(request, response) {
  var verificationCode = (Math.floor(Math.random()*900000)) + 100000 ;
  var user = request.user();
  user.set("phoneVerificationCode", verificationCode);
  user.save();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in (have active session) then you can do following:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('get-current-user', async (request) => {
   return request.user;
});
```

Once you call above end-point, it will return current user.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: test-app" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Parse-Session-Token: r:8729a7099f8c3d87979f4dfd2e5b59df" \
http://localhost:1337/functions/get-current-user
```